# Angular 2 event catching between sibling components

Tags: events, angular

I've just begun learning Angular 2, and this is my first ever Stack Overflow question, so here goes...

I have an outer component with two nested inner components. I have a button in `InnerComponent1` that, when clicked, fires an event that the outer component catches, which then passes the value (always true) into `InnerComponent2`. `InnerComponent2` is displayed (*ngIf) based on that value.

It works.

Buuuut.. `InnerComponent2` has a button that, when clicked, makes that value false, which hides the component.

That works too.

But once I've hidden `InnerComponent2`, the button in `InnerComponent1` that displays `InnerComponent2` no longer works. I'm not seeing any errors and I have confirmed that the outer component is still receiving the events.

Here's a plnkr that shows the scenario: http://plnkr.co/edit/X5YnNVm0dpFwA4ddv4u7?p=preview

Any thoughts?

Thanks very much.

**Outer component**

```
//our root app component
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {Inner1Component} from 'src/inner1';
import {Inner2Component} from 'src/inner2';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  providers: [],
  template: `
    <p>OuterComponent</p>
    <inner1 (show2)="show2Clicked = $event"></inner1>
    <inner2 [showMe]="show2Clicked"></inner2>
  `,
  directives: [Inner1Component, Inner2Component]
})
export class App {
  show2Clicked: boolean;
}
```

**InnerComponent1**

```
import {Component, EventEmitter, Output} from 'angular2/core'

@Component({
  selector: 'inner1',
  providers: [],
  template: `
    <p>inner1</p>
    <button (click)="showInner2()">Show inner2</button>
  `,
  directives: []
})
export class Inner1Component {
  @Output() show2 = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

  showInner2() {
    this.show2.emit(true);
  }
}
```

**InnerComponent2**

```
import {Component, Input} from 'angular2/core'

@Component({
  selector: 'inner2',
  providers: [],
  template: `
    <div *ngIf="showMe">
      <p>Inner2</p>
      <button (click)="showMe = false">Cancel</button>
    </div>
  `,
  directives: []
})
export class Inner2Component {
  @Input() showMe: boolean;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `showMe` and `shwo2Clicked` values get out of sync.

I added and `EventEmitter` to `<inner2>` and changed

```
<inner2 [showMe]="show2Clicked"></inner2>
```

to

```
<inner2 [(showMe)]="show2Clicked"></inner2>
```

I guess it's now working as you expect

http://plnkr.co/edit/tXzr3XgTrgMWMVzAw8d7?p=preview

**update**

The binding `[showMe]` works only in one direction. When `show2Clicked` is set to true, `showMe` will be set to true as well. Cancel sets `showMe` back to false. If then `show2Clicked` is set to `true` again, nothing happens because it is already `true` and `showMe` isn't updated. With the `EventEmitter` and two-way shorthand binding `[(showMe)]`, `show2Clicked` is also set to `false` when `showMe` is set to `false` and setting it to `true` is actually a change that is propagated down though the binding.

`[(showMe)]="show2Clicked"` is a shorthand for `[showMe]="show2Clicked" (showMeChange)="show2Clicked=$event"` and the shorthand only works when the output has the same name as the input but with an additional `Change`

Comment: Perfect. Thanks very much for your speedy response. Works as expected. Just to clarify exactly what is going here: We need the event emitter in `inner2` just to trigger the re-evaluation of the variables and the rerender? Because the `showMeChange` event that is emitted isn't captured anywhere.

Comment: Shorthand. Gotcha. That's exactly what I was looking for. **Thanks very much.** The official Angular2 documentation is still lacking, understandably.

Comment: this thing is critical for it to work `shorthand only works when the output has the same name as the input but with an additional Change`  And you are awesome @Günter Zöchbauer

Comment: Was finally added to the docs :) https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#two-way

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, switching a form upon clicking a button from sibling component. My solution was to use a common service.

so in component 1 :

```
<button (click)="showMessageForm()" >
showForm = true;
showMessageForm() {
    this.messageService.switchMessageForm(this.showForm);
    this.showForm = !this.showForm;
}
```

in service :

```
switchMessageFormEvent = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
switchMessageForm(bSwitch:boolean) {
    this.switchMessageFormEvent.emit(bSwitch);
}
```

in component 2 :

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.messageService.switchMessageFormEvent.subscribe(
        (bSwitch: boolean) => {
            if(bSwitch) {
                $('.message-input').slideDown("normal");
            }else {
                this.myForm.reset();
                $('.message-input').slideUp("normal");
            }
        }
    );
}
```