# Communicate between sibling components Angular 2

Tags: angular, eventemitter, angular2-components

I tried to follow this answer but its too confusing [Angular 2 event catching between sibling components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35685801/angular-2-event-catching-between-sibling-components)

I want to call a method in **child component 1** when something is clicked on **child component 2**

Child component 2 emits an event called trackClick.

**Parent Component:**

```
<div>

    <audio-player></audio-player>

    <audio-albums></audio-albums>

</div>
```

**Child Component 1 (audio-player)**

```
// Don't know what to do here, want to call this function

trackChanged(track){
    console.log("YES!! " + track);
}
```

**Child Component 2 (audio-albums)**

```
<li class="track" (click)="playTrack(track)"> </li>

@Output() trackClick = new EventEmitter<any>();

playTrack(track):void{
    console.log("calling playTrack from child 2:" + track);  
    this.trackClick.next([track]);
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can't do it like this. first you have to get child2 in parent by using @ViewChild(Child2) (it's important to select ViewChild by component not by string). then you have to catch the event in parent and execute whatever method you want on child2. more or less something like this:

```
import { AudioAlbumsComponent }  from '...';
import { AudioPlayerComponent }  from '...';

@Component({ 
  template: `
    <div>
      <audio-player></audio-player>
      <audio-albums (trackClick)="onTrackClicked($event)"></audio-albums>
    </div>`,
  directives: [AudioPlayerComponent, AudioAlbumsComponent],
}) 

export class Parent {
  @ViewChild(AudioPlayerComponent) private audioPlayer: AudioPlayerComponent;

  onTrackClicked($event) {
    this.audioPlayer.trackChanged($event);
  }

}
```

Comment: ok i was afraid it would have to be child2->parent->child1, thanks ill try

Answer (score 8):

An alternative (template-only way) is

```
<audio-player #audioPlayer></audio-player>
<audio-albums (trackClick)="audioPlayer.trackChanged($event)"></audio-albums>
```

The event handler references `<audio-player>` by the template variable `#audioPlayer`.

Comment: oh nice this is much better instead of going through parent...thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

Parent

```
<div>
    <audio-player (trackchanged)="trackChanged($event);></audio-player>
    <audio-albums></audio-albums>
</div>

@ViewChild(Child2) child2Component: Child2Component;

trackChanged(value:any) {
 child2Component.trackChanged(value);
}
```

Child1

```
...
@Output() trackchanged= new EventEmitter();
...
playTrack() {
    this.trackchanged.emit({value: this.track});
}
```

Child2

```
trackChanged(track){
    console.log("YES!! " + track);
}
```