# How to trigger function from one component to another in angular2?

Tags: angular

I have two components componentA and componentB. Both of them are sibblings, and are children of componentMother.

I want to make it such that when I click on a button on componentA, it triggers a function call on componentB.

Is the way to do this using a service with an observable and having componentA emit events that componentB subscribes to or is there a better/best practice way?

Comment: That, or emit an event from an output in A, to which the parent component subscribes and sets an input or calls a method on B.

Comment: check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39132385/communicate-between-sibling-components-anguar-2/39132530#39132530. it should answer your question

Comment: I would do a local small service, it's the cleanest way.

Comment: @tibbus Could you show a basic example of how these components would be connected to the service?

Comment: @kit Why you don't post the answer (with the source and adaptations) here?

Comment: because I've already answered it in provided link. I don't like to duplicate stuff.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I would probably use a service that uses a `Subject`. This way it can be both published to and subscribed from

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

class SomeService {
  private _subject = new Subject<any>();

  newEvent(event) {
    this._subject.next(event);
  }

  get events$ () {
    return this._subject.asObservable();
  }
}
```

The from your components, one can publish and one can subscribe

```
@NgModule({
  providers: [ SomeService ]
})
class AppModule {}

@Component()
class ComponentOne {
  constructor(private service: SomeService) {}

  onClick() {
    service.newEvent('clicked!');
  }
}

@Component()
class ComponentTwo {
  constructor(private service: SomeService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.service.events$.forEach(event => console.log(event));
  }
}
```

**See also:**

- [Getting Started on Subjects](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/gettingstarted/subjects.md)

Answer (score 1):

Use 
**RxJS SUBJECT (~EventEmitter):**`import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject'`;

Subject service will allow you to enable bi-directional communication for a parent component and its children.

**Reference** : https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service

For more details of

> RxJs SUBJECT

check this one  : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rdK92pf3abs