# ng2-charts not redraw while using angular service

Tags: angular, ng2-charts

I'm trying to use an angular service to redraw ng2 chart.
While using the graph component locally the graph **getting** redraw.

When I try to use angular shared service the graphs **not redraw**

anyone knows what I'm doing wrong?

Service injection is done with this tutorial:
https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4

Example for the graph taken from here
https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-charts/blob/development/demo/src/app/components/charts/line-chart-demo.ts

https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-charts/blob/development/demo/src/app/components/charts/line-chart-demo.html

My code

CitiesComponent:

```
export class CitiesComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private globals: Globals, public graphService: GraphService) {}
```

html:

```
....
<button (click)="graphService.randomGraph()">CLICK</button>
....
```

GraphService:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {PricesLineChartComponentComponent} from './prices-line-chart-component/prices-line-chart-component.component';

@Injectable()
export class GraphService {

  constructor(public pricesComponent: PricesLineChartComponentComponent) { }

  public randomGraph(){
      this.pricesComponent.randomize();

  }


}
```

Comment: When are you calling randomGraph()? Can you post that code?

Comment: @OscarPaz I have added the call reference.

Comment: I figured out I have to use events. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40313770/how-to-trigger-function-from-one-component-to-another-in-angular2