# get different data from component to other component in angular 4

Tags: angular

I want to show my component data into other component using service. i have 3 component.

service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Injectable()


export class GlobalserviceService {

  private _listners = new Subject<any>();

  listen(): Observable<any> {
    return this._listners.asObservable();
  }    

  filter(filterBy: string) {
    this._listners.next(filterBy);
  }
}
```

component one

```
mapLegends = [
    {
      name: 'hello',
      checked: true,
  color:'#1ac3ec'
    },
    {
      name: 'hello 1',
      checked: true,
  color:'#7dc55c'
    },
]
```

component two

```
mapLegends = [
    {
      name: 'hello 3',
      checked: true,
  color:'#1ac3ec'
    },
    {
      name: 'hello 4',
      checked: true,
  color:'#7dc55c'
    },
]
```

component three

```
mapLegends = [
    {
      name: 'hello 5',
      checked: true,
  color:'#1ac3ec'
    },
    {
      name: 'hello 6',
      checked: true,
  color:'#7dc55c'
    },
]
```

i want each component data into other component. i do not want to use input or output property.

**its a sibling component**

**it would be great help to give me demo**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 Sibling Component Communication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35884451/angular-2-sibling-component-communication)

Comment: i do not want parent and child component interaction.

Comment: Read the second answer, which covers specifically your case

Comment: also i have data in my component not in service.

Comment: **HMM**  Go and use LocalStorage :)

Answer (score 0):

Angular has no strict rules for sibling component communication. If the @Input/@Output decorators are not suitable solution for you, than you could simply create "shared service" register it as singelton and inject them where they are needed - [Example](https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/sharing-data-between-angular-components-four-methods/) "Unrelated Components: Sharing Data with a Service" paragraph is what you are looking for . If you need to catch events instead of data you could use the  [EventEmitter](https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter). Working example is available in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35685801/angular-2-event-catching-between-sibling-components).