# How to access a mat-table element in ComponentA from ComponentB

Tags: angular, angular-material

A Visual Studio 2019 project with an Angular 12 UI.

All of the code was originally in CompA of the UI, specifically there was a mat-table:

`<table mat-table #myTable>`

as well as a click event on the table rows, so that when a row is clicked, its background color changed to yellow:

```
   ...
  <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: myColumns;" (click)="setRowColor($event)"></mat-row>
</table>
```

In the ts file, I have a ViewChild to the table:

`@ViewChild('myTable', { static: true }) myTableVar: MatTable<any>`

plus code to handle setting/clearing the background color:

```
  setRowColor(ev: Event) {
    let el: HTMLElement = ev.currentTarget as HTMLElement;
    if (el.style.backgroundColor === 'yellow')
      el.style.backgroundColor = '';
    else
      el.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
  }
```

There is also a button on CompA that when clicked, will cycle through all rows in the table, processing any row that had a background color of yellow, and then clearing the background color for the row:

```
processRowsInMatTable() {
    const el: HTMLElement[] = this.myTableVar._getRenderedRows(this.myTableVar._rowOutlet);
    el.forEach(e => {
      const eHtml: HTMLElement = e as HTMLElement;
      if (eHtml.style.backgroundColor === 'yellow') {
        //some processing;
        eHtml.style.backgroundColor = '';
      }
    });
  }
```

Everything was working as expected. However as CompA was getting too large, CompB was created, and the button that would cycle through all the rows in the mat-table is now in CompB. How can I get a reference to CompA.myTable in CompB, so that I can perform the logic in method processRowsInMatTable (which is also in CompB now)? Also, there is no parent/child relationship between A and B.

Comment: could you show your CompA and CompB code and how they are rendered and related.

Comment: What's the structure of these 2 components? Are they nested or siblings?

Comment: @Babis They are siblings.

Comment: @barnumBailey You should check how `EventEmitter` works so that you can emit an event from the one component and pass the value into the second one.

Comment: @BarnumBailey check this post, It should help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35685801/angular-2-event-catching-between-sibling-components

Comment: I do use event emitter when someone double clicks on a mat-table row, I didn't show that code.  I've thought of possibly using an event emit when a user single clicks on a row. While I could do something like store off the data from the single row click, I'm left with the problem of clearing the row background color after processing.

Comment: @Babis, thank you, I will check that post.

Comment: @Babis - the post was very helpful, thank you.

Comment: @BarnumBailey I'm glad it helped :)